# Which syntax should been for second div?

Tags: css

```
<style>
.panel{
border:1px solid #000;
}
</style>

<div class="body">
    <div class="panel"></div>
    <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

We would like set style `border-top:0px;` for second `div.panel`
Which syntax should been for second `div.panel`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dqt1o01o/3/ if second==last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the `:nth-child` selector. In this case, the nth-child value will be 2. See the below snippet :

```css
.panel{
  border:1px solid #000;
}

div.panel:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class="panel">a</div>
    <div class="panel">b</div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Yes, it will work on all modern browsers. In case of IE, it should work on atleast 9 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this would be the most simple one, using `.panel + .panel` for the selector. This will select any direct `.panel` sibling of another.

Your CSS would then look like:

```
.panel {
  border: 1px solid #000;
} .panel + .panel {
  border-top: 0;
} .panel + .panel + .panel {
  border-top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: You fail to mention that this would apply to all subsequent div's i.e. it would apply CSS on all div's except the first one. Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/9zuddf9x/ . Having said that, it does seem sufficient (while also being a different approach) if additional div's are not involved. +1

Comment: This is easily fixed by applying a third rule to cancel the effects for any subsequent `.panel` elements. This wasn't shown to be the case in the question though.

Comment: @Pluto can you tell more abbout third rule ?

Comment: I'll edit it in. It'll cancel the effect any third `.panel`, but note that it'll apply for the second `.panel` even if there's some other element prior to the two `.panel` elements. A variation of the second rule would fix that.

Comment: Well, you see now you are applying **two rules just to achieve what a single `nth-child` rule can do.**

Comment: The `nth-child` pseudo selector doesn't have full compatibility (which may or may not be relevant for the OP) and it doesn't actually select the second `.panel`, just the second `.panel` child. If there was a hidden element before all the `.panel` elements, the entire functionality wouldn't work anymore.